# WSO2 API Manager fails with [PassThroughMessageProcessor-58] WARN DataPublisher Event queue is full, unable to process the event for endpoint group

Tags: wso2, wso2-das

We are doing evaluation for metering purpose using WSO2 API Manager and DAS. (Latest versions)

Environment:

WSO2 API Manager runs as 2 node active-active deployment model using Hazlecast. (4 Core 8GB Ram) &
DAS runs as single node.
Both are connecting to backend RDBMS as mysql.
DAS and MYSQL shares the same server of 12 Core 24GB RAM. We dedicatedly allocated 12GB to MYSQL.

We started the test at the rate of 750reads/sec and everything went well for 27hrs until the metering reaches 72 Million and after which we have got the below error.

At API Manager: [PassThroughMessageProcessor-130]  WARN DataPublisher Event queue is full, unable to process the event for endpoint Group.

At Das: (After 10 mins), we have got INFO {com.leansoft.bigqueue.page.MappedPageFactoryImpl} -  Page file /$DAS_HOME/repository/data/index_staging_queues/4P/index/page-12.dat was just deleted. {com.leansoft.bigqueue.page.MappedPageFactoryImpl}.

Is this something that we have reached the limit w.r.t the infra setup or some performance issues w.r.t DAS. Can you please help us?

Answer (score 0):

You need to tune the server performance of [DAS](https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS310/Performance+Tuning) and [APIM](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Tuning+Performance)